# Show that a set does satisfy Caratheodory's condition.

Tags: measure-theory

Let X be a non-empty set and $\mu^*$ be an outer measure on X. Show that if $ A \subset X$ has the property that:
$$\mu^*(A)=0 \lor  \mu^*(X-A)=0$$
then  A does satisfy Caratheodory's condition:
$$\forall B \subset X \ \ \ \mu^*(B)=\mu^*(B \cap A)+\mu^*(B-A)$$

I got lost a bit during this exercise and I would  be grateful for any help.

I showed that $\mu^*(X) \le \mu^*(A)$ or $\mu^*(X) \le \mu^*(X-A)$ so $X \subset A$ or $X\subset X-A$, so either $A=X$ or $A=\emptyset$, and such sets does  satisfy Caratheodory's condition - is my take on this exercise true?

Comment: $\mu^*(X) \le \mu^*(A)$ does not imply $X \subset A$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always $\mu^*(B) \le \mu^*(B \cap A) + \mu^*(B - A)$ so only the reverse inequality needs to be proved.

From this point the proof requires only monotonicity.

If $\mu^*(A) = 0$ then $\mu^*(B \cap A)= 0$, so that $\mu^*(B \cap A) + \mu^*(B - A) = \mu^*(B - A) \le \mu^*(B)$.

If $\mu^*(X - A) = 0$ then $\mu^*(B - A)= 0$, so that $\mu^*(B \cap A) + \mu^*(B - A) = \mu^*(B \cap A) \le \mu^*(B)$.